# Unity Netcode - ServerRPC only works when called from host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer

I have a Prefab I am trying to spawn from clients. I previously had a lot more code than what is displayed below but I have broken it down to the bare minimum to solve the problem, however I can't seem to figure out the error.

- The prefab is in Network Manager and it has a Network Object attached.
- I have a reference to the Prefab attached to an OnlineManager script where the serverRPC is  attached to.
- If the Host spawns the prefab it's visible to the client
- If the client attempts to spawn the prefab I get NullReferenceException and it's not visible.

```
   // This is called once the user has selected the button to spawn prefab
   public void Init()
    {
        
        // PrefabRef is the prefab attached to this script
        ghostPrefab = prefabRef;

        

        SpawnGhostObjectServerRpc();
        

        

    }


    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SpawnGhostObjectServerRpc()
    {


        instantiatedPrefab = Instantiate(ghostPrefab.gameObject);

        instantiatedPrefab.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);


    }
```

I have spent about 20ish or more hours trying different things, researching, watching youtube videos. I just can't put my finger on what im doing wrong. I have even tried switching network solutions, but ended up reverting back to NetCode.

Comment: In general a client shouldn't be network spawning the object but the host right? Sounds like there should be only one instance shared among everyone?

Comment: @derHugo That does make sense. I believe I can get it working from that, will give it a try here soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As derHugo mentioned -- Having one instance shared among everyone did seem to work for me. Although I struggled getting it to work in netcode, I was able to successfully get it working with FishNet.

Just in case others are struggling here is what I did.

```
    public override void OnStartClient()
{
    base.OnStartClient();
    if (!base.IsOwner)
    {
        // Disable the online manager for everyone except the host
        GetComponent<OnlineManager>().enabled = false;
        

    }
   
}

 // Called from another class when the client or host selects a button
 public void Init()
{
   
    

    if (spawnedObject == null)
    {
        SpawnGhostObjectServerRpc(objToSpawn, this);
    }

}

[ServerRpc]
private void SpawnGhostObjectServerRpc(GameObject obj, OnlineManager instance)
{
    GameObject spawned = Instantiate(obj);
    //spawned = Instantiate(obj);
    ServerManager.Spawn(spawned);

    
}

// I believe this observer rpc will allow me to access the spawned object 
// to be able to move/delete it after it has been spawned
[ObserversRpc]
public void SetSpawnedObject(GameObject spawned, OnlineManager script)
{
    instance.spawnedObject = spawned;
}
```